# Batch, output word

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
Title OutputWords
:Input
cls
echo Enter a number:
set /p input=
if %input% == "1" set /a word=One
if %input% == "2" set /a word=Two
if %input% == "3" set /a word=Three
if %input% == "4" set /a word=Four
if %input% == "5" set /a word=Five
if %input% == "6" set /a word=Six
if %input% == "7" set /a word=Seven
if %input% == "8" set /a word=Eight
if %input% == "9" set /a word=Nine
if %input% == "0" set /a word=Zero
goto Show
:Show
cls
echo Number: %word%
pause
goto Input
```

So how do I make it so that when I write a number, it says the number with words, why isn't this working?

Comment: Remove the `/a`'s and change the `%input%`'s to `"%input%"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the dilemma is with the quotes around the numbers. Batch is very finicky about quotes and spacing-- try:

```
if %input%==1 set /a word=One
```

or

```
if "%input%"=="1" set /a word=One
```

Another problem you should be having, is that when you use `set /a`, `set` expects the value you store to be an equation, which it will evaluate. Since you aren't having it do math, try:

```
if %input%==1 set word=One
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let me recommend to use the quoted version, because this can also handle empty values of `%input%` while the unquoted one can't. Alternatively, you could place `set /a input+=0` after `set /p input=` to convert `%input%` to a number, so it is never empty; then you could use `if %input% equ 1` to do a true numeric comparison...